# Two color borders with straight transition

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve a differently colored border at the bottom of my `div`, but without the diagonal edges like so:

[image]

I have looked into the `:before` selector, but I couldn't get it to work. How can one achieve this in css. I prefer to be IE7 compatible as well.

Here is a small fiddle that I've created. http://jsfiddle.net/EYjCV/11/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/LA4Lh/)

HTML:

```
<div class="bordered">Hey Hey Hey</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.bordered {
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
}
.bordered:before {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-5px; left:0; right:0;
    content:" ";
    color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid lime;
}​
```

Pseudo-elements aren't supported by IE7. There's a fantastic polyfill called [**ie9.js**](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) , or you can add an additional `<span>` element and follow the method below:

---

[**Demo crossbrowser**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/LA4Lh/)

HTML:

```
<div class="bordered">Hey Hey Hey<span></span></div>​
```

CSS:

```
.bordered {
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
}
.bordered span {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-5px; left:0; right:0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid lime;
}​
```

Comment: Ha, only a few seconds faster than me! +1 anyhow.

Comment: Seems like a solid answer. I only have the problem that I am using multiple of these `div`s next to each other. `right:0;` therefore gives some issues. How can I make the border as large as the original div?

Comment: It shouldn't give issues @Marnix, if you add `position:relative;` to the parent. If you experience some problems, please show me an extended fiddle / code...

Answer (score 1):

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/kQmbb/).

Here's the outline, HTML:

```
<div class = "yourdiv">Glee is awesome!</div>
```

CSS:

```
.yourdiv{
    border: 10px skyblue solid; /*or whatever your border definition is*/
    position: relative; /*necessary*/
    /*stuff for prettiness*/
    background: rgb(0, 162, 232);
    color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.yourdiv:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px; /*width of border, negated*/
    height: 10px; /*width of border*/
    left: 0;
    right: 0; /*make sure it spans the whole space horizontally*/
    background: orange; /*blue, in your case*/
}
```

For this to work in **IE7** (since it [doesn't support](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent) `:after` and `:before` pseudoselectors), create a `div` inside your `div`, give it a class (suppose it's `.borderdiv`), and style it with the same things that `.yourdiv:after` is styled with above.

Modified version that works on IE7: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/X4JPb/).